# Spring Data JPA not using AttributeConverter in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application that designates an `AttributeConverter` for an entity that converts an enum from uppercase to title case for storage in the database.

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customerleads")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CustomerLead implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    @Convert(converter = CustomerLeadTypeConverter.class)
    private CustomerLeadType type = CustomerLeadType.OPEN;
}
```

And the following AttributeConverter class:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class CustomerLeadTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<CustomerLeadType, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(CustomerLeadType attribute) {
        switch (attribute) {
            case OPEN:
                return "Open";
            case CLOSED:
                return "Closed";
            case DELETED:
                return "Deleted";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + attribute);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerLeadType convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        switch (dbData) {
            case "Open":
                return OPEN;
            case "Closed":
                return CLOSED;
            case "Deleted":
                return DELETED;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + dbData);
        }
    }
}
```

Neither `@Converter(autoApply = true)` nor the `@Convert(converter = CustomerLeadTypeConverter.class)` seem to trigger the conversion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Drop the `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`:

```
// @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "type")
@Convert(converter = CustomerLeadTypeConverter.class)
private CustomerLeadType type = CustomerLeadType.OPEN;
```

Comment: Just curious. Can we not use any annotations on custom converted types? like `@Lob`? I see `@Column` though. What type of annotations are not allowed?

Comment: @ArunGowda If I understand correctly, the problem is '@Enumerated' and '@Convert' are in conflict.  They're instructing to use two mutually exclusive methods to convert between an enum and another value type.  That's why you can't use both.